# How to bypass slider captcha to solve puzzle using selenium?(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, captcha

On the mentioned website, After searching for the token, a slider captcha appears.

An example of the captcha:
[image]

I want to bypass the slider captcha. I took reference from the first solution in [Unable to let my script slide a button to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824421/unable-to-let-my-script-slide-a-button-to-the-right)

My approach would be to slowly move until the slider is in the right place and after that, the new page opens.

The website is: `https://www.ems.com.cn/english/`

My approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = 'https://www.ems.com.cn/english/'

driver.get(url)

token = 'CY008445045CN'

token_space = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='el-input__inner']")

token_space.send_keys(token)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='el-icon-search']").click()
time.sleep(4)

slider_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='slide-verify-slider']")
slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='slide-verify-slider-mask-item']")

# Perform sliding action
actions.move_to_element(slider).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(slider_container.size['width'], 0).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find_element_by_xpath
```

is deprecated, you should use:

```
find_element(By.XPATH, value="")
```

Here is updated version of your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = 'https://www.ems.com.cn/english/'

driver.get(url)

token = 'CY008445045CN'

token_space = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//input[@class='el-input__inner']")

token_space.send_keys(token)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//i[@class='el-icon-search']").click()
time.sleep(8)

slider_container = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value="//div[@class='slide-verify-slider']")
slider = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='slide-verify-slider-mask-item']")

# Perform sliding action
for x in range(10000):
    
    actions.move_to_element(slider).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(x, 0).release().perform()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

To resolve captcha you must release button in correct place, not just slide.

Much better way to get data is to use REST API

[REST API](https://www.trackingmore.com/pricing.html)

Comment: This code works for me, but the sites I am trying to scrape has a limit of only 6 attempts. Do you maybe have an idea how to solve it? Here is the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142531/dealing-with-puzzle-captcha-using-selenium-that-has-a-limit-of-5-attempts